Is this a valid joint distribution?
Is the following a valid joint distribution? I tried integrating over the 2 regions, 0 < x < y < 1 and 0 < y < 2-x, but can't seem to get 1. The joint distribution is
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases} 
x, & \text{if } 0 < x < y < 1 \text{ or } 0 < y < 2 - x < 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
Edit: Thank you for the suggestions. From the question, I identified 2 regions,  $\ 0 < x < y < 1 $ and $\ 0 < y < 2 - x < 1$
I tried the following integrations:
$\int_0^1 \int_0^y x \, dx \, dy$ + $\int_0^1 \int_1^{2-y} x \, dx \, dy$
I tried switching the order as well, this time integrating with reference to $\ y: 
\int_0^1 \int_x^1 x \, dy \, dx$ + $\int_1^2 \int_0^{2-x} x \, dy \, dx$
Am I doing something wrongly with the above integrals?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Please include in your question the details of the Integrals that you used. The most common error made by students is in figuring out the limits on the various integrals.  Also, add the self-study tag, and possibly, the probability tag too.

It may not be true that ${0<x<y<1}\cap {0<y<2-x<1} = \varnothing$

I did the same thing you did. And no I did not get 1 I got a value less than 1.

Where did you get the feeling this should be a valid joint distribution from?

@Andrew what makes you think that? Even if it isn't null, it is measure zero, no?

@Snared, thank you for trying to verify the distribution with me. I saw this question while practicing exam papers. This was the exact distribution given, so I'm quite confused whether there was an error in the question or if I'm doing it wrongly.

Suppose $f$ were a joint distribution, and draw $(x,y)$ randomly, according to $f$.
We know $P(0 \le x \le 2)=1$ since $f$ is $0$ whenever $x < 0$ or $x>2$. However, since $f$ is a joint distribution,
$$P(0 \le x \le 2) = \int_0^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\ dy\ dx = \left(\int_0^1\int_x^1 x\ dy\ dx\right)+\left(\int_1^2 \int_0^{2-x} x \ dy\ dx\right) = \frac 1 6 + \frac 4 6 = \frac 5 6$$
We just proved $\frac 5 6 = 1$ assuming $f$ were a joint distribution, which is a contradiction. Hence, $f$ is not a joint distribution.
